# Control sound to only play once in XNA

Tags: xna

I use a sound each time a key is pressed to fire a missile. But it doesn't sound nice. I guess it's because the the sound is repeated so many times while the key is pressed down and that the code is within the Update method. I'm looking for a simple solution to just play the sound once when key is pressed? (I have tested to use a boolean variable to be true the first time and then false after det the sound has been played, but this didn't worked well because, when and where should I set it to true again) Help is preciated!

```
// Fire
if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
{
missile.launchMissile(spaceship.spaceshipPosition, spaceship.spaceshipDirection);

soundExplosion.Play();
}
```

EDIT New code that isn't working!?

```
            KeyboardState keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

        KeyboardState prevKeyboardState;

        prevKeyboardState = keyboardState;

        keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();


        if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && prevKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
        {
            missile.launchMissile(spaceship.spaceshipPosition, spaceship.spaceshipDirection);
            soundExplosion.Play();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your previous keyboard state as well

```
KeyBoardState prevKeyboardState;
```

then in your update

```
prevKeyboardState = keyboardState;
keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && prevKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
{
  //your code
}
```

You're basically just triggering the sound tons of times every second making it sound awful.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help, but the code isn't working! I have tried all kind of kombinations with your code! What could be wrong? I guess the first line of KeyboardState has a big 'B', when it should be a small 'b'!? More help is preciated!

Comment: It is difficult to tell where you are creating these.  If you're putting KeyBoardState prevKeyboardState; in your update call that is your issue, but I can't tell by your post.